# Automagically relating nodes of a single content type

Tags: nodes, views

I have a content type (e.g. Target) which has a title and body. I will have about a 1000 nodes of this content type. I want to be able to create a view that renders not not only the title and body of this type of node, but also associated/related nodes.

I don't want to have to manually associate nodes (based on taxonomy or by adding an entity reference). Instead, I want the view to automatically search for the Title of a given node in the Body field of all other nodes of this type and associate those nodes that contain the given node's Title.

I'm new to Drupal, but believe I've gotten my head around the basics and have several Views configured and working. But I can't seem to find any guidance on achieving the above and not sure how to do that in Drupal/Views, although I know this is achievable in straight SQL.

Any ideas, advice?

Answer (score 0):

Remeber that views is some kind a [query builder](https://www.drupal.org/node/2287909), even better it gives you tools to alter its content, query and so on. See [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

Comment: I am not at all familiar with using Drupal hook-alters. Is there no way to do this via the Views UI then?

Comment: Without a field relationing them I think no, at least one I can think of